# Can I save the hid_t value of a data set in an hdf5 for quick access at a later point in time?

Tags: hdf5

I am trying to access a particular dataset within an HDF5 file multiple times.
Does the `hid_t` value, that is returned upon opening the dataset, persist once the file is closed and can it be used to directly access that dataset at a later time (after reopening the file of course)?

I.e. consider the following simple case:-

I have a hdf5 file that contains a folder ("foo") which in turn contains a dataset ("bar")
My current approach (following all the examples that I've seen) is:-

```
Open file
   Open folder "foo"
     Open dataset "bar"
     Read dataset "bar"
     Close dataset "bar"
  Close folder "foo"
Close file
```

Once I have the `hid_t` value for the "bar" dataset
I would like to store it and then next time I need to (read) access it directly i.e.:-

```
Open File
   Open stored "bar" (using stored hid_t value)
   Read "bar"
   Close "bar"
Close file
```

Is this possible?
Is this advisable?
Is there anything I need to consider further if I do this?

Thanks in advance for any replies

Comment: What language are you using? You don't really "open" folders (groups) or datasets -- you are creating a HDF5 object. Creating an object requires very little overhead. Reading data can (depending on the size of the dataset). You can open the dataset object with the full path. Use this sequence: 1) Open File, 2) Open dataset "/foo/bar"

Comment: In case it isn't clear, you can simply call `H5Dopen(filehandle, "/foo/bar")` to open the dataset `bar` in directory `foo`.

Comment: @kcw78 - I'm using C# and the HDF.PInvoke wrapper. I didn't involve the language as I thought it was a generic question.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer appears to be "no". You cannot store the `hid_t` value returned by the call to `h5Dopen` and expect to be able to reuse it as a short cut to reopen the dataset.

The correct approach is to store the 'path' to the dataset as a `string` (in the above example "/foo/bar") and use that to directly open the dataset - i.e.

```
H5Dopen(filehandle, path);
```

Thanks to Kcw78 and Homer512 for essentially answering this/providing the correct way to address this, in the comments above.